# Kohana bootstrap error

Tags: php, kohana

I have uploaded my code (using Kohana) but I get this error and I don't know what to do. The path to the file seems correct.

```
Warning: require(/home/sites/xxxx.org/web/system/classes/kohana/core.php):
  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
  /home/sites/xxx.org/web/application/bootstrap.php on line 6

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
  '/home/sites/xxx.org/web/system/classes/kohana/core.php'
  (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in 
  /home/sites/xxx.org/web/application/bootstrap.php on line 6
```

Comment: You say the path 'seems' correct. Can you say whether it's correct or not? Use the path to open the file to test.

Comment: ok you are right how can i fix that i've tryed to go to that particular file and it's keep saying it doesn't exist but i can see it there...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following. Does the path exist?

Comment: the path to the directory kohana it's ok

Comment: Kohana version? v3.3 uses `Kohana/Core.php` instead of `kohana/core.php`.

Comment: thank you that fixed but it came up to something even worse ohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL questions was not found on this server.

Comment: Well, its another question ;)

Comment: that means your routes need to be updated, with proper casing, as Kohana 3.3 uses CamelCase filenames, separated by underlines